# How to make writing on ElasticSearch safe?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel

I have a problem with ElasticSearch.
My application write on Elasticsearch index using Apache Camel routes. Sometimes it happens that my Elasticsearch is not reachable and therefore the data that should be written at that time is lost. Is there a way to make it safe to write to Elasticsearch in order to retrieve data that was not stored during the down period?

Comment: Based on your description it seems like your problem is with ElasticSearch only and not ActiveMQ.

Comment: Would you be able to add some code snippets of how your configuration is glued and what highlights Camel failing to write to your target data store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using a [redelivery policy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_configuring_redeliverypolicy_redeliver_options). For longer term outages, or when redelivery attempts are exhausted, you'd want something like a [dead letter queue](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/dead-letter-channel.html) so the data is not lost.